# Code Uploaded with VSCode+PlatformIO Is Performing Dramatically Slower Than with Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, esp32, platformio

I am trying to transition a project to PlatformIO and the same code is performing very differently depending on which IDE I use to upload to the board.

I am using the FastAccellStepper library to control a stepper with an ESP32 dev board.
I calculate the steps required to run the stepper for a period of time, say 10sec.
Code uploaded with the Arduino IDE runs for 10s, but the stepper runs slower and longer (~30s) when uploaded with PlatformIO.

I am at a loss of what to try to fix this issue.  Is there something PIO does with debugging/interrupts that can be messing up the timing of FastAccellLibrary?  Is the board clock speed settable in PIO somewhere?

```
;platformio.ini
platform = espressif32
board = ttgo-lora32-v1
framework = arduino
lib_deps = 
    bodmer/TFT_eSPI@^2.3.3
    lennarthennigs/Button2@^1.2.0
    gin66/FastAccelStepper@^0.8.0
monitor_speed = 115200
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to `platformio.ini` in the relevant section:

`board_build.f_cpu = 240000000L`

and use the latest version.